# How to change the nested object array by key value type in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-loops

I would like to know how modify array of objects in javascript.

i.e for obj change the `value` key  array to string when `value` is array

change the `value` key string to array when `value` is string

also, how to convert output as input `obj` and (vice-versa-<input as output) in javascript

```
function newObject(obj){
  var result = obj.map(e=>typeof e.value === "string" ?
  {...e, value: [e.value] } :
   e.value.map(value => ({...e,value})) 
  ).flat()
  console.log(result);
  return result;

}
```

scenario1

```
input:
obj =[
 { id: 0, key: "s1", value: ["listA","listB"], img:"" },
 { id: 1, key: "s2", value: ["listC"], img: "" },
 { id: 2, key: "s3", value: ["listD","listE","listF"], img: "" }
]

Expected output:
[
  { id: 0, key: "s1", value: "listA,listB", img:""},
  { id: 1, key: "s2", value: "listC", img:""},
  { id: 2, key: "s3", value: "listD,listE,listF", img:""}
]
```

scenario 2

```
input
[
  { id: 0, key: "s1", value: "listA,listB", img:""},
  { id: 1, key: "s2", value: "listC", img:""},
  { id: 2, key: "s3", value: "listD,listE,listF", img:""}
]

Expected Output
[
 { id: 0, key: "s1", value: ["listA","listB"], img:"" },
 { id: 1, key: "s2", value: ["listC"], img: "" },
 { id: 2, key: "s3", value: ["listD","listE","listF"], img: "" }
]
```

Comment: What happened to `listF` in the last object of your output array? (first code block?)

Comment: @NickParsons thanks for reply, updated the code, was missed out

Comment: `arr.forEach(item => item.value = item.value.join('')` and `arr.forEach(item => item.value = item.value.split(',')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can return a new object with all the properties and values of the current object (`...o`), along with an update `value` property. The update value property will check if `o.value` is an array (checked using [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)), if it is, it will [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the elements into a string, it is a string (ie: not an array), it will [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the commas to convert the string into an array.

See example below:

```js
function newObject(arr){
  return arr.map(o => ({
    ...o,
    value: Array.isArray(o.value) ? o.value.join() : o.value.split(',')
  }));
}

const arr1 = [ { id: 0, key: "s1", value: ["listA","listB"], img:"" }, { id: 1, key: "s2", value: ["listC"], img: "" }, { id: 2, key: "s3", value: ["listD","listE","listF"], img: "" } ];
const arr2 = [ { id: 0, key: "s1", value: "listA,listB", img:""}, { id: 1, key: "s2", value: "listC", img:""}, { id: 2, key: "s3", value: "listD,listE,listF", img:""} ];

const res1 = newObject(arr1);
const res2 = newObject(arr2);
console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
```

Answer (score 2):

we can use for loop to achieve more performance

```js
let arr_1 = [
  { id: 0, key: "s1", value: ["listA","listB"], img:"" },
  { id: 1, key: "s2", value: ["listC"], img: "" },
  { id: 2, key: "s3", value: ["listD","listE","listF"], img: "" },

  { id: 0, key: "s1", value: "listA,listB", img:""},
  { id: 1, key: "s2", value: "listC", img:""},
  { id: 2, key: "s3", value: "listD,listE,listF", img:""}
]


const f = (arr) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let x = arr[i].value        
    arr[i].value = Array.isArray(x) ? x.join() : x.split(',')
  }
console.log(arr)
}

f(arr_1)
```